# Apply more than one orderBy in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know we can create a query builder and order by base on specific column in **Laravel**

```
$visitors = Visitor::orderBy('visit_count', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
        ->where('os', 'not like', '%bot%')
        ->where('country', '=', 'US')
        ->get();
```

But I am not sure - if we can apply more than one `orderBy` condition. Can we do that ?

For Ex. Get all the visitors order by visit_count AND show the latest one first ...

**Any advises or tips for me ?**

Comment: its Query Builder btw

Comment: Opp... Sorry, willl update the title. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another orderBy:

```
$visitors = Visitor::orderBy('visit_count', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('visit_count', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->where('os', 'not like', '%bot%')
    ->where('country', '=', 'US')
    ->get();
```

EDIT: just realized you already had it in there. The answer is yes. You can add as many orderBy's in a query as you want, just like in SQL.